# Why does trim() make a non existent variable exist?

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$a=$_POST['dsaghgjjkhfdsfdsfsdfdsjhkhkhgj'];

if(isset($a))
{
    echo"exists";
}
else
{
    echo"does not exist";
}
```

echos the value "does not exist", HOWEVER when i apply trim to the $_POST variable,

```
$a=trim($_POST['dsaghgjjkhfdsfdsfsdfdsjhkhkhgj']);

if(isset($a))
{
    echo"exists";
}
else
{
    echo"does not exist";
}
```

the code will echo "exists". Why does passing in a non-existing $_POST variable to trim() magically makes it exist?

Comment: You have no check in your code at all that checks whether `$_POST['dsaghgjjkhfdsfdsfsdfdsjhkhkhgj']` exists or not. So how can you say so that `$_POST['dsaghgjjkhfdsfdsfsdfdsjhkhkhgj']` is magically made into existance when used with `trim()`? You have neither showed that it did not exist nor that it does exist. You're obviously mixing things here, perhaps you're irritated by the fact that `trim()` returns a string, always? Perhaps you're running to a conclusion too fast while not checking the basics?

Comment: Recommended reading: [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/367456)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly what happens, step by step.

When you refer to `$_POST['...']` in the second code snippet this notice is issued:

> Notice: Undefined index: ... on line ...

You don't get the notice as your `error_reporting` level does not include `E_NOTICE`. The intermediate `$_POST['...']` is evaluated `NULL` and `trim(NULL)` returns an empty string. So `$a` is assigned an empty string.

If you prepend `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `ini_set("display_errors", "on")` to your script, you will see the actual errors/warnings/notices issued.

Answer (score 3):

Because trim returns a string, regardless of its inputs, see http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php.

```
php > var_dump(NULL);
NULL
php > var_dump(trim(NULL));
string(0) ""
```

A string, even if it is empty, is declared as "defined". This is why `isset` returns `true` then.

Comment: it doesn't explain what happens

Comment: Yes it does. trim creates a string from its inputs.

Comment: It *did not* explain what happens. Originally (when I posted my comment) your answer didn't have anything but code. Also it makes sense to mention implicit casting, since it's caused not by returning a string, but by casting a `null`

Comment: This does not explain how $_POST['...'] results in NULL.

Comment: It does not "result" in NULL. Accessing a var which is not defined automatically is "NULL" when accessing it.

Answer (score 2):

This is what [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) does:

> Returns `TRUE` if **var** exists and has value other than `NULL`, `FALSE` otherwise.

In your first example, the `$_POST` variable doesn’t exist. [Non-existing variables have the value `null`](http://php.net/language.types.null):

> A variable is considered to be *null* if:
>
> - it has been assigned the constant `NULL`.
> - it has not been set to any value yet.
> - it has been `unset()`.

So `$a` does also equal `null`. Although `$a` exists, it has the value `null`, so `isset` returns `false`.

In your second example, `null` is passed to `trim`, which returns an empty string:

```
var_dump(trim(null)); // string(0) ""
```

So `$a` does also equal an empty string. And since `$a` exists and has value other than `null`, `isset` returns `true`.

Comment: I would also remark that a E_NOTICE is issued when referring to non existing variables and array indices.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `empty()` function. `trim()` is returning an empty string != NULL:

```
$a=trim($_POST['dsaghgjjkhfdsfdsfsdfdsjhkhkhgj']);

if(empty($a))
{
    echo"does not exist";
}
else
{
    echo"exists";
}
```

From php.net:

The following things are considered to be empty:

```
"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
$var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
```